# Select button: change to bootstrap version

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How from this code:

```
 <%= f.select :difficulty, [ 'Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard'], :prompt => 'Select One', input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

Make this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

I tried everything

Comment: What is the language/technology of the first snippet? Mentioning it explicitly and adding the tags will draw more attention.

Comment: Yes I forgotten. Thanks for a comment and edit my missing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your FormHelper `prompt` inside brackets  `{ :prompt => 'Select One' }` and remove `input_html:`. If you're manually adding an ID like in the output displayed in your question you can add it with the class as in the example below.

*Note this was tested in Rails 4.2.3, Ruby 2.1.5p273 with the Bootstrap-SASS Gem on v3.3.5 of Bootstrap.

Hopefully this helps.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select :difficulty, [ "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" ], { :prompt => 'Select One' }, { class: "form-control", :id => "select" } %>
</div>
```